# Knockout - Observing jQuery.active

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

Can Knockout observe values, such as `jQuery.active`, that are changed externally? I want to make a loading animation when there is an active AJAX call.

Comment: You could create a custom knockout binding for the value: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html. Not sure what jQuery.active is/does, so can't provide any code for you!

Comment: `jQuery.active` is a number of active AJAX requests. Standard computed or custom binding is not working, since `jQuery` sets the value by itself. Basically, I am trying to subscribe to a 'nonobservable'.

Comment: Out of the box subscribing to a property such as active is going to be a bit of a challenge because it is not set by Knockout and the callbacks won't be fired when the value is changed.  You could continuously poll the property but that is going to be expensive.  Without knowing too much about the .active property my first thought would be to fork the method, add a class call, create an observable there, and then your subscription would work, but that is going outside of the context of this question.

Comment: I thought as much. I'm going with `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` events, incrementing and decrementing a numeric observable when they fire.

Comment: Binding to `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` events is pretty much the de facto way of accomplishing this. If you want Knockout to be aware of these events, you can set the observable value in the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Knockout is able to do that without [watching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) the jQuery.active variable and/or adding many lines of code. That seems far too much complicated to just display a loading animation.

I would recommend doing everything (show/hiding your animation?) with jQuery.

Another solution would be to show/hide your animation before and after each ajax request via a ko.observable boolean, but if you are doing a lot of different ajax requests, from different models, it will become a mess.

Comment: A boolean observable would be inappropriate due to asynchronous nature of AJAX, so I'm thinking of subscribing two functions to `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` events, to increment/decrement a numeric observable, and show the animation when that number is > 0.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking about a boolean being updated from the success callback. I use it sometimes, but it is only useful when you have one particular ajax call, not for a global solution. Listening to ajaxStart and ajaxStop seems to be a good solution, actually.